# How to get all users in a telegram channel using telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm new to telethon and python. I have installed telethon in python3 and I want to get all members of a telegram channel or a group . I was searching a lot in the internet and found below code . And I'm trying really hard to understand it .Telegram documentation is not enough to do this . Is there a better solution ?

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ResolveUsernameRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetAdminLogRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetParticipantsRequest

from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsRecent
from telethon.tl.types import InputChannel
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelAdminLogEventsFilter
from telethon.tl.types import InputUserSelf
from telethon.tl.types import InputUser
# These example values won't work. You must get your own api_id and
# api_hash from https://my.telegram.org, under API Development.
api_id = 12345
api_hash = '8710a45f0f81d383qwertyuiop'
phone_number = '+123456789'

client = TelegramClient(phone_number, api_id, api_hash)





client.session.report_errors = False
client.connect()

if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone_number)
    client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter the code: '))

channel = client(ResolveUsernameRequest('channelusername')) # Your channel username

user = client(ResolveUsernameRequest('admin')) # Your channel admin username
admins = [InputUserSelf(), InputUser(user.users[0].id, user.users[0].access_hash)] # admins
admins = [] # No need admins for join and leave and invite filters

filter = None # All events
filter = ChannelAdminLogEventsFilter(True, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True)
cont = 0
list = [0,100,200,300]
for num in list:
    result = client(GetParticipantsRequest(InputChannel(channel.chats[0].id, channel.chats[0].access_hash), filter, num, 100))
    for _user in result.users:
        print( str(_user.id) + ';' + str(_user.username) + ';' + str(_user.first_name) + ';' + str(_user.last_name) )
with open(''.join(['users/', str(_user.id)]), 'w') as f: f.write(str(_user.id))
```

But I'm getting this error . What have I missed ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 51, in <module>
    result = client(GetParticipantsRequest(InputChannel(channel.chats[0].id, channel.chats[0].access_hash), filter, num, 100))
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'hash'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sean answer won't make any difference.

Your code works for older Telethon versions. In the new versions, a new argument `hash` is added to `GetParticipantsRequest` method. Therefore, you need to pass `hash` as an argument too. Add `hash=0` like this:

`result = client(GetParticipantsRequest(InputChannel(channel.chats[0].id, channel.chats[0].access_hash), filter, num, 100, 0))`

Note that the `hash` of the request is not the channel hash. It's a special hash calculated based on the participants you already know about, so Telegram can avoid resending the whole thing. You can just leave it to 0.

[Here](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/wiki/Retrieving-all-chat-members) is an up-to-date example from official Telethon wiki.

Answer (score 5):

```
channel = client(ResolveUsernameRequest('channel_name'))
user_list = client.iter_participants(entity=channel)
for _user in user_list:
    print(_user)
```

or

```
user_list = client.get_participants(entity=channel)
for _user in user_list:
    print(_user)
```

[from](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/688)

Answer (score 5):

you can try the code below, it works, I tested. But I do have a question, because the Telethon library doesn't extra all the users, it only extra like 90% of the users. I think it somehow skipped some ones... don't know why.

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty
import csv

api_id = 123456
api_hash = 'YOUR_API_HASH'
phone = '+111111111111'
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)

client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))


chats = []
last_date = None
chunk_size = 200
groups=[]
 
result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
             offset_date=last_date,
             offset_id=0,
             offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
             limit=chunk_size,
             hash = 0
         ))
chats.extend(result.chats)

for chat in chats:
    try:
        if chat.megagroup== True:
            groups.append(chat)
    except:
        continue

print('Choose a group to scrape members from:')
i=0
for g in groups:
    print(str(i) + '- ' + g.title)
    i+=1

g_index = input("Enter a Number: ")
target_group=groups[int(g_index)]

print('Fetching Members...')
all_participants = []
all_participants = client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=True)

print('Saving In file...')
with open("members.csv","w",encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    writer.writerow(['username','user id', 'access hash','name','group', 'group id'])
    for user in all_participants:
        if user.username:
            username= user.username
        else:
            username= ""
        if user.first_name:
            first_name= user.first_name
        else:
            first_name= ""
        if user.last_name:
            last_name= user.last_name
        else:
            last_name= ""
        name= (first_name + ' ' + last_name).strip()
        writer.writerow([username,user.id,user.access_hash,name,target_group.title, target_group.id])      
print('Members scraped successfully.')
```

Answer (score 4):

I think You can use this code in the new version of `Telethon`

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetParticipantsRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetFullChannelRequest
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsSearch

api_id = XXXXX
api_hash = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
phone_number = '+98XXXXXXXX'
################################################
channel_username = 'tehrandb'
################################################

client = TelegramClient('session_name',api_id,api_hash)

assert client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone_number)
    me = client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter code: '))

# ---------------------------------------
offset = 0
limit = 200
my_filter = ChannelParticipantsSearch('')
all_participants = []
while_condition = True
# ---------------------------------------
channel = client(GetFullChannelRequest(channel_username))
while while_condition:
    participants = client(GetParticipantsRequest(channel=channel_username, filter=my_filter, offset=offset, limit=limit, hash=0))
    all_participants.extend(participants.users)
    offset += len(participants.users)
    if len(participants.users) < limit:
         while_condition = False
```

I used ‍`Telethon V0.19`, but the previous versions are pretty much the same

Answer (score 3):

The simple way to get all users of a telegram channel using telethon. And make sure that you have valid permissions used for the channel or group (caused by GetParticipantsRequest).

`from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ResolveUsernameRequest`

```
channel = await client(ResolveUsernameRequest('channel_name'))
async for _user in client.iter_participants(entity=channel):
      print(_user)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `client.invoke()` instead of `client()`.

You can refer to [official guide](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/4e5dede7fef655a9a945e9809728581f8c77afbb/readthedocs/extra/advanced-usage/users-and-chats.rst#retrieving-all-chat-members-channels-too).

Comment: just because you typed an answer :)