# Are "user" bots made with telethon allowed on Telegram?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I'm trying to make a bot for telegram using the telethon library. I would like my bot to be able to retrieve all members of any group that it's been added to which is [not currently possible with the telegram bot API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51050063/get-all-users-of-telegram-group).

Because of this limitation, I made a new telegram account/app for my bot (using a Google Voice number) to use the python telegram Client, telethon, to gain user level access to the telegram API.

After playing around with it for a bit, I received this error:

```
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.PhoneNumberBannedError: The used phone number has been banned from Telegram and cannot be used anymore. Maybe check https://www.telegram.org/faq_spam (caused by SendCodeRequest)
```

After trying to login again from my phone I received a similar notification:

> This phone number is banned.

I submitted a support ticket which was never responded to, but I was somehow able to login again with the Google Voice number the next day.

My question is: are we allowed to make bots for telegram with user level permissions using the telethon client? I cannot find any explicit rules about this in the [telegram API ToS](https://core.telegram.org/api/terms). However, the [telethon docs mention in passing](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/concepts/botapi-vs-mtproto.html):

> If your application ever needs user features because bots cannot do certain things, you will be able to easily login as a user and even keep your bot without having to learn a new library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're allowed to use any userbots. the ban probability is exact same as of an unofficial app of Telegram in Google play and other platform.

You're however going to be suspected and pre-banned by Telegram if you're from certain countries or you use VOIP phone numbers. Telegram doesn't like such numbers and might require you appeal to unban it manually.

It's fully their decision.

i, have been using my account in forks and userbots, etc.. for many years, so new accounts are suspected to be up to no good and frozen. try with your own number or buy extra legit one.

Telegram is pretty spammy platform and lately they have increased the ban situation.

Comment: Can you provide a link to any details in their docs or ToS that explain the VoIP number ban? Also, have you added your userbot to many groups and/or interacted with many accounts from it?

Comment: Telegram is kind of a secretive company on server-side, they don't mention everything in ToS, they have their ways of dealing with things silently. bans have been higher lately. you'd notice how many times it was mentioned in support groups pretty easily.

My userbot is my own account, it's in around 400 groups. i usually use AFK that respond to personal messages automatically when I'm offline, and other commands i use taken from other userbots like automatic name changing, and other. it's pretty active account, but nothing too shady going on. it's all good since many years and i lost count.